# EasyMock / PowerMock import question

Tags: java, junit, easymock, powermock

I'm experiencing some problems I can't quite figure out, and one site I found suggested a problem with incompatibilities with verify() if the mocks were created with PowerMock.

When I type a line to create a mock, Eclipse is telling me the method is ambiguous, and I end up having to specify it as EasyMock.createMock or PowerMock.createMock.

I had originally just started with EasyMock and then switched to PowerMock. Does the order of import statements matter, and if you're using PowerMock is it important not to include certain EasyMock stuff?

Here's what I've got:

```
import org.easymock.EasyMock;  
import org.junit.*;  
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;  

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;  
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.*;  
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;  
import org.powermock.api.easymock.*;  
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.*;  
import org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.*;  
import org.powermock.api.mockito.*;  
import org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.*;  
import org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.*;  
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.*;  
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.*;
```

There may be some redundancies there. Is a conflict possible? And is the order important in order to eliminate the ambiguity?

Thanks.

Craig

Answer (score 4):

Taking from a `PowerMock` example

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.aryEq;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expectLastCall;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertSame;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createMock;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.expectNew;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.replay;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verify;
```

Notice that they don't import createMock from both libraries. You shouldn't import anything from `EasyMock` that you are already using `PowerMock` for.